# How can I copy the text from a website to a string in c++?

Tags: c++, api, curl, libraries

I am trying to connect to an online API, get all the text on the website, and copy+paste it to a string.

The URL is [https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[KEYHERE]](https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=%5BKEYHERE%5D)
And [https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=[MyKey]&profile=[MyProfile]](https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=%5BMyKey%5D&profile=%5BMyProfile%5D)
(the URL is censored).

this is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string URLPurse = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=[MyKey]&profile=[MyProfile]";
    string URLEnder = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[MyKey]";
    //read text from both APIs
    string answerPurse = [text from the player api];
    string answerEnder = [text from the bazzar api];

    // Do stuff with the text
}
```

I am EXTREAMLY new to programming and I don't know how to download or use cURL, but is there a way to do it without external libraries? if there isn't can you explain how can I download and use cURL to achieve this? (I am using Windows 7 with 32-bit and Code::Blocks). I also can't use any other programming languages like java for example.

(I know I use too many libraries)

Comment: ok i'll change it

Comment: Mind you, I think I'm overkilling it. [Windows has a buttload of functions for  mucking with pages on the internet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_wininet/). You can probably use a few of them to make the connection and suck down the file you want.

Comment: "*is there a way to do it without external libraries?*" - in a word, no. Even if you were to use a plain vanilla TCP socket and implement the HTTP/S protocols yourself, you are still using an external library for the socket itself, and preferably the SSL/TLS protocol, too. The OS provides the socket library, and some OSes provide an SSL/TLS library, too. In which case, you should see if your target OS provides an HTTP/S API, too (such as WinInet/WinHTTP on Windows), let it do all of the hard work for you.

Comment: @clickednebula3 ignore my ranting in the first comment. Pulling in cURL and MSYS2 is overkill and the last thing you need to do while learning a language is have to fight with tools. Read through the link in the second comment. Microsoft has some excellent documentation to get you started and if you get stuck you'll be in a much better place to ask questions. That said, this might not be a particularly easy project to dive into with a weak C++ background. C++ is a tough language to learn as you go from code samples and tutorials.

Comment: @clickednebula3 That's closer to a [mre], but not quite there. However, it's close, and since you seem amenable to this sort of change, I'll push it a bit closer.

Answer (score 0):

try using selenium, it is in python and I believe c++ also, you can target html elements and use them however you would like

Comment: I don't know how to install libraries, if i knew i could've used cURL

Comment: cURL is available in DLL form, there is nothing really to install for that, just `#include` the headers in your code and link to the DLL's `.lib` file, and then deploy the DLL with your app.  If you want to use the static version of cURL, that would be a different matter, since you would likely have to recompile cURL's source code for your particular compiler before you can then use it.

Comment: where do i put the DLL?

Comment: IMHO, the best place to put DLLs is in the same location as your executable.  Another good place is in the Operating System folder that contains DLLs.  The common search path is the current directory (that the executable resides in), then the system folder.